# What does DisableOutOfProcTaskHost do?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, msbuild

I recently ran into a problem with building a WPF application with the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3036,5):
> error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because
> MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4"
> and architecture "x64".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime
> and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the
> required executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" exists
> and can be run.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3058,7):
> error MSB4028: The "GenerateResource" task's outputs could not be
> retrieved from the "FilesWritten" parameter. Object does not match
> target type.

What helped me was to set a system variable `DISABLEOUTOFPROCTASKHOST` to `1`. This solution is googled and I could not find an explanation on what is happening and why `DISABLEOUTOFPROCTASKHOST` helped me.

Can anyone explain to me what was the cause of the error and why the variable helped me?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I was not able to go through your answer in depth until today, I will check it soon and will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your side**, it seems that you have compiled a resource with a different architecture than the host MSBuild instance is. It may be caused by the problem with different versions of your project resource files or using different versions of the code that need to launch an additional process of a differeet version of **MSBuild**(`arm64\msbuild.exe`) using a different **CLR**.

**So** the approach is that you should let **MSBuild** always follow the current file build version, that is, it can automatically switch between different versions of the build mechanism under the same **MSBuild** build process.

The solution is to add these xml node in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>   
     <GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
     <GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Or** add environment variable `DISABLEOUTOFPROCTASKHOST` to `1`.(let it switch between different versions of build mechanism under the same `MSBuild.exe` build process)

Comment: I have all projects in the solution set with platform target as x64 (I am not sure if that means anything in the context of this answer). The strangest thing is, that it compiled without any issues when I cloned the solution for the first time (it worked for couple days). As far as I am aware, there is no instance of msbuild ran manually, everything is done by visual studio. The exactly same code that does not work on my pc, works on jenkins build server without the environment variable set.

Comment: Or that I think the issue is related to your VS IDE or its environment. Please check if your PC has installed other third party tool, program, vs installed extensions that interfaces the performance of msbuild or VS IDE which causes the differences of msbuild. Or disable any third party vs extensions. Besides, you could use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error.
but By Repairing Visual Studio 2019,
close VS, delete .vs hidden folder (under solution folder) ,bin and obj folder then restart your VS .
Fortunately My problem was solved.